# eBay Browse API: shopping cart add item doesn't work

Tags: ebay-api

Working with [Ebay's Browse API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/overview.html) I'm having an issue with the [/shopping_cart/add_item](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/shopping_cart/methods/addItem) method, when I call it, it systematically returns an error 204.

I'm working on the API's sandbox. The calls are made from an iOS application in Canada. Until then, I had no issues requesting and retrieving data from responses.

Here's how I proceed:

1. Using the sandbox, I retrieve mock items with [/item_summary/search](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item_summary/methods/search).
2. The user goes through the [OAuth process](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-qref-auth-code-grant.html) and grants his shopping cart access to my app. It returns a user access token that I use for the following request.
3. Finally, I call [add_item](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/shopping_cart/methods/addItem) with the following parameters:

Request JSON parameters:

```
{"quantity": 1, "itemId": "v1|110385018358|0"}
```

Request headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer [sandbox user access token from step 2.]
Content-Type: application/json
X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID: EBAY_US
```

Then I get an empty response (aka error 204), while it shouldn't [as mentioned in the documentation](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/shopping_cart/methods/addItem#h2-output).
The response I get only contains headers which are the following:

```
{
    Status Code: 204, Headers {
        Connection = ( "keep-alive" );
        "Content-Encoding" = ( gzip );
        "Content-Length" = ( 0 );
        "Content-Type" = ( "application/json" );
        Date = ( "Thu, 22 Nov 2018 15:14:32 GMT" );
        RlogId = ( "t6q%60ktkjvdbwrfsl%2Bbmsgcufboja%7Ct6n%3C%3Dsm%7Eufhuoluefqqgwj%284%3F34%3F11%2Busqdrrp%2Bufmadh%7B%2Bceb%7Ce4-fij-1673bfca0ca-0x133" );
        "Set-Cookie" = ( "dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**5dd7fb58^;Domain=.ebay.com;Expires=Sat, 21-Nov-2020 15:14:32 GMT;Path=/" );
        "X-EBAY-C-REQUEST-ID" = ( "ri=LVOZVdAO%2FSpS,rci=n76DxeaOd61P0WBf" );
        "X-EBAY-C-VERSION" = ( "1.0.0" );
        "X-EBAY-REQUEST-ID" = ( "1673bfca0a9.a0962ac.25e7e.fffdc702!/buy/browse/v1/shopping_cart!10.9.98.172!esbnewesbngcos[]!add_item!10.9.103.137!r1remshopcartapi-envadvcdhidzs5k[ItemClient[!Ginger.ViewItemServiceV1.litedetails!10.9.99.212!r1viappsvc-envadvcdhidzs5k[]]!ShopcartServiceClient[!Ginger.shopcase.v2.POST!10.9.101.40!r1scartsvc-envadvcdhidzs5k[]]]" );
        "X-EBAY-SVC-EP-COOKIELET" = ( "321=0001542899671242" );
        "X-EBAY-SVC-TRACKING-DATA" = ( "<a>nqt=AA**&!_epec=7,6,8&nqc=AA**</a>" );
    }
}
```

---

Moreover, logged in the [ebay sandbox website](http://pages.sandbox.ebay.com/) with the test user I used above, if I [open the cart](https://cart.payments.sandbox.ebay.com/sc/view), I get an error page stating:

> We were unable to load your cart. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact Customer Support or send us feedback.

Still from the sandbox website, when I [open any item](http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/itm/Amazon-Echo-2nd-Generation-2017-w-Improved-sound-by-Dolby-Charcoal-Fabric-NEW/110385029959?hash=item19b375e347:g:KJMAAOSwhwBZ4yQq:rk:3:pf:0&src=urllib), I get another error stating:

> Unfortunately, access to this particular item has been blocked due to legal restrictions in some countries. [...]

---

I still hope the problem is on me and not on Ebay as their API is still a Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... It was nowhere in the API documentation, but hidden somewhere on the Sandbox website page "[unsupported feature list for the sandbox](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=684)":

> Cart is not supported.  You may see some functionality working, like adding items to your cart, but please do not depend on or expect cart to function properly.

Although it states that AddItem may work, it actually does not, so I guess it is expected and that I should take this as the answer to my question.

Quite frustrating... 
I guess I all I can do is to wait for Ebay's partnership approval.